# Is it a good idea to cache webclient creation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I am using spring webclient to call external APIs. I have a builder which returns webclient. My question, is that a good idea to cache the created webclient for a specific URL.Below is my code.

```
@Cacheable(value = "somevalue", cacheManager = "cachemnager", key = "#url")
public WebClient getWebClient(String url, Map<String, String> headers,List<ExchangeFilterFunction> filterFunctions) {
        return WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .defaultHeaders(addsome headers)
            .filters(list -> list.addAll(filterFunctions))
            .build();
}
```

Also I have to call multiple API with different url/params/headers so I have to create multiple webclient as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad idea to me because :

1. spring-boot already auto-configures a `WebClient.Builder` for you. It also `pre-configured` [default codec](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.developing-web-applications.spring-webflux.httpcodecs) in this builder for converting HTTP request/reponse to/from different type of java object. Creating it by yourself means that you need to configure this stuff by yourself.
2. If you really want to do it, it is overkill to use spring cache abstraction because most probably an application does not need to create many `WebClient` that will cause the JVM has the chance to run out of memory. So you do not need the expiration and eviction feature provided by the cache , just use a simple `HashMap` to keep it simple.

The [official docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.webclient) strongly advises to inject the pre-configured `WebClient.Builder` to create and configure the WebClient. So just follow it . Also see the docs for an example for how to do it.